# Time stamp calculation on SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I'm trying to display the total travel time that each customer in data time format (00:00:00)

But I'm confused to whether I should just do

SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(endtime - starttime))

or

SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(**TIME_TO_SEC**(endtime - starttime)))

or

SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(**TIME_TO_SEC**(endtime) - **TIME_TO_SEC**(starttime))

*if endtime and startime is in datetime format*

which one should be the right way to do it. I'm getting a different result for first and the second one

Comment: What happens if it took, say 100 hours, to travel?  Would you want to report something like `100:10:05`?  Would it make more sense to just report in hours, with a possible fractional component?

Comment: we were told to express it in HH/MM/SS. Im just curios whether we should change the time to seconds before calculation and turn it back again

Answer (score 1):

1st:

convert `endtime` and `starttime` into timestamp using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

2nd:

subtract them

> note: the result will be in seconds

`(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endtime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime))`

to determine how much time did the costumer consume

3rd:

convert the result into time

`SEC_TO_TIME( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endtime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime)) )`

so your final query should be like this

`SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endtime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(starttime)) ) FROM travel`

Comment: If start date and end date is already a time stamp we don't have to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Of your three options, I would recommend:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(endtime)
```

- TIME_TO_SEC(starttime))

First, I think this is clearest on what you want to do:

- Convert the date/times to seconds
- Add up the seconds
- Convert back to a time

Second, MySQL treats date/time values as numbers in a numeric context.  This can produce strange results because 2018-09-13 is turned into 20,180,913, and that is not usually what you want.